# Basic jQuery fadeIn, fadeOut issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below are my code, When I click Next Box it show the Box B second box and hide Box A and so on then if Box C is loaded the last box it will show alert that "There is no Box left"

**My CSS**

```
.hide{ display:none}
```

**My HTML**

```
<div class="q">Box A</div>
<div class="q hide">Box B</div>
<div class="q hide">Box C</div>
<a href="#" id="btnNext">Next Box</a>
<div id="alert" class="hide">There is no Box left</div>
```

**My JS script**

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnNext").click( function() {
        $(this).parents('.q').fadeOut(500, function() {
              if( $('.q:last') ) {
                   $("#alert").fadeIn( 500 );
              } else {
                   $(this).next().fadeIn( 500 );
              }       
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead.

```
 $("#btnNext").click(function(){
     $('.q:visible').fadeOut(500, function(){
         if($(this).index()==$('.q').length-1){
                        $("#alert").fadeIn(500);
                    }else{  
                        $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
                    }                
                });

            });
```

You don't need to change anything in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).parents('.q')` will not work; none of the `.q` divs are the parent of the `a`.  Also, you need to ensure you only select the first `.q`.  Additionally, once a `div` has faded out, it's still in the DOM, so you'll want to remove it from the DOM once you're done.  Otherwise, the same one will fade out each time.

```
$(this).parent().find('.q')[0].fadeOut(500, function() {
    if ($(this).is(':last')) {
        $('#alert').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
    }
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: @jacob your right I try it but when I click next it show the alert "There is no Box left" not the next box B here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/NeABT/6/

Comment: @jacob there is no happen when I click "Next Box"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
 $("#btnNext").click(function(){
                $('.q').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    if($(this).index() == $('.q').length-1){
                        $("#alert").fadeIn(500);
                    }else{  
                        $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
                    }                
                });

            });
});
```